# React-router-dom params undefined in nested route after using link

Tags: react-router

I need a switch component to have access to route params. The switch is rendered in one of the routes but its also rendered outside of it. Is there a way to get the same params in the component rendered outside of the route? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Certainly, but we can't help much with code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good pattern to not directly pass params through the route and keep those simple with the view component. You can use `useContext`, and then have each component(route) plug into that state using the `useContext` hook in the component.

for example...

app.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Routes } from "./auth/routes.js";
import { GlobalContext } from './globals/GlobalContext.js';

const App = () => {
  // variables
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('hello world');

  // render
  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={{someState, setSomeState}}>
        <Router children={Routes} basename={process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL} />
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

GlobalContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const GlobalContext = createContext("");
```

routes.js

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// views
import ViewOne from '../views/ViewOne.js';
import ViewTwo from '../views/ViewTwo.js';

// globals
import { frontendLinks } from '../globals/index.js';

export const Routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={frontendLinks.viewOne} component={ViewOne}></Route>
    <Route exact path={frontendLinks.viewTwo} component={ViewTwo}></Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

now the views...

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

// globals
import { GlobalContext } from '../globals/GlobalContext.js';

const ViewOne = () => {
  const { someState } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{someState}<h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ViewOne;
```

and

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

// globals
import { GlobalContext } from '../globals/GlobalContext.js';

const ViewTwo = () => {
  const { someState } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{someState}<h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ViewTwo;
```

If you don't want to manage shared state in your app.js file, I suggest you check out this video for managing `useContext` state in different files > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52W__dKdNnU